# sqLite - Lock per table OR entire db file?

Tags: database, sqlite, concurrency, locking

Super quick question. Just want to verify I understand sqlite locking correctly in that the entire database is locked, not a specific table within the database, is that correct?

Should I break all my tables into their own unique database if I plan to make changes to each table simultaneously? (or close to it)

Thanks!

Comment: Simply put, SQLite is not a multiuser database. It isn't intended to be. With the WAL (write-ahead log) it can support *some* concurrent use, but it's still going to fall short of a real multiuser database. However, whether your exact scenario is going to be supported by WAL I don't know.

Comment: I'm not using using it as such and am unsure as to what I wrote that insinuated that. Just looking to verify that the lock is for the database file itself, not a table within the file.

Comment: You're right, it is a file lock, but the WAL circumvents *some* of that by allowing some types of transactions and changes to end up in the log and be committed once the previous lock is closed.

Comment: It is all [documented](https://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html).

Comment: Great thanks, that's all i needed. Feel free to submit as an answer so I can accept